# Rails records not displayed when grouped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a book model which for the sake of this question has 5 fields (id, title, issue, release_date, print_run). I'm trying to populate a sales table grouped by title so here's what I have in my controller:

```
@books = Book.all.where("release_date > ?", "2012-05-01").where("print_run > ?", "1").group(:title)
```

And in my view here's part of the table:

```
<% @books.each do |title| %>
<tr>
<td><%= title.title %></td>
<td class="text-center">
<% if title.print_run > 1 && title.release_date.between?((Date.today - 12.month).beginning_of_month, (Date.today - 12.month).end_of_month) %>
<%= title.print_run %>
<% else %>
    0
<% end %>
</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Each book has one issue per month so I have a table set up with 14 columns (title, one for each month, and total). I would like to display the print_run of each TITLE by month, but when I use `group(:title)` in the controller, it only displays the print run for the last month (but the rest are 0). If I remove `group(:title)` from the controller, it displays all the print runs in the correct month BUT has each issue in its own run.

Here are a couple of images to illustrate the issue. Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what your condition is, you are checking for beginning and last of same month is your query

Comment: (Date.today - 12.months).beginning_of_month displays exactly as it should...2014-05-01 and (Date.today - 12.months).end_of_month as 2014-05-31 so the release_date is correctly falling between that

Comment: Please understand you are saying if release date between  1-5-2014 and 31-5-2014 then show print_run else 0

Comment: Pardeep, if this is the case then why does it work when i remove the group(:title)? In fact, I removed everything so that @books = Book.all and that is still the case. In my testing, I have determined that using group(:title) will actually ONLY display the print_run for the last created book with that title.

Comment: Can you paste here what @books contain with group and without group

Comment: With:
    @books = Book.all.group(:title)

Without:

Answer (score 0):

As an FYI i reworked the whole things...in my controller I have now:

```
@book = Book.where(:rdate => (Date.today - 12.month)..(Date.today - 1.month)).where("printrun > ?", "1").select("DISTINCT(title)").group("title").order("title")
```

...and then in my view:

```
<%= Book.where(:title => title.title, :rdate => (Date.today - 1.month).beginning_of_month..(Date.today - 1.month).end_of_month).sum(:printrun) %>
```

Now the view part is probably not ideal and I'll move that into the controller at some point, but problem solved. Note that I had to add the select("DISTINCT(title)").group("title") in the controller. The first part solves my unique problem but let to a PGError because PostgreSQL apparent groups by ID by default. By specifying the group("title") i resolved the issue (even if this seems apparently redundant).

Hope this helps the next person with a similar issue.